# Showing/hiding swagger UI endpoints based on API key

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I have swagger set up but it shows all the controllers for everyone.  I'd like to only show controllers based on API key permissions, so they'll have to enter their API key in the `Explore` section of swagger to see anything. Is this do-able?

Comment: What library/framework are you using - Swashbuckle, Swagger-Net or any other ?

Comment: I'm using Swashbuckle

Comment: I don't think so, as swagger ui is implemented in javascript based on the .json generated by swashbuckle. Even if you could, I wouldn't recommend it. But you might be able to pretend you support multiple versions as separate .json files?

Comment: I guess there may be a way to describe "Multiple Authentication" https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/#multiple  schemes and requirements, so that api's are displayed as locked / unlocked based on how you authenticate.

Comment: you can create a documentfilter and filter only required api. here a [article](https://medium.com/@niteshsinghal85/api-filtering-on-swaggerui-by-role-in-net-core-6006b9bb98c4) for .net core which does filtering based on roles. but I guess concept is same.

Comment: Is there a different library/framework that does this easily? Being able to dynamically check and show controllers/endpoints based on API key?

Comment: any library will provide some functionality and a way to extend the functionality, so such requirements are very specific which can be easily extended. so in the end you take any library but you have to extend them with your specific requirement.

Answer (score 3):

If we talk about [Swashbuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.WebApi) package then we need to use implement `IDocumentFilter`.

Some initial information you can review from this [post](https://medium.com/@alexandre.malavasi/show-only-specific-apis-on-swagger-asp-net-core-aff91f6b9834).

Basic scenario:

- Define custom `Attribute`
- Setup this attribute to `Controllers` / `Actions`
- Implement filtration logic in your `DocumentFilter` class

Code sample available here:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class LicenseValidatorAttribute : Attribute
{
    public FeatureType Feature { get; set; }
}

public class FeatureDocumentFilter : IDocumentFilter
{
    private readonly IFeatureService _featureService;

    public FeatureDocumentFilter(IFeatureService featureService)
    {
        _featureService = featureService;
    }

    public void Apply(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
    {
        foreach (var api in context.ApiDescriptions)
        {
            var attribute = api.CustomAttributes().OfType<FeatureValidatorAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();

            if (attribute != null)
            {
                var success = _featureService.ValidateFeature(attribute.Feature);

                if (!success.Valid)
                {
                    var route = "/" + api.RelativePath;
                    swaggerDoc.Paths.Remove(route);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you get `FeatureType`, `IFeatureService`, `OpenApiDocument` and `DocumentFilterContext` from? The IDocumentFilter.Apply method only accepts `SwaggerDocument`, `SchemaRegistry`, `IApiExplorer` parameters.  Also how do you get the request context here to be able to check headers/API key?